# Is it possible to add a custom message to the Rx.Net Timeout operator

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, reactive, rx.net

I am trying to read a stream of data from device and find the valid data in it.
It is a set of zeroes with some data in between.
Something like:

0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0,0 and so on.

What is emitted after processing is the sum of the group of non zero data e.g.

9,9

I have two timeout operators in my code. And unfortunately both of them have same message:

`System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.`

So I am not able to provide more context to the user as if where the error occured e.g. The data stream went silent or We have a datastream running but we are getting zeroes only.

Is there a way I can add my own message rather than the regular TimeoutException message?

Here is my pseudo code:

```
var _handle = 
        _source.Select(x => x.Item1)
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) // If the stream goes silent here the timeout is raised.
        .EmitSumOfDataNonZeroPoints()
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)) // If no valid group of nonzero data is found the timeout is raised.
        .Subscribe(
            someProcessing => {},
            ex => {
                _errorInObservableMessage = ex.Message;
            },
            () => {}
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Timeout` operator has an overload where you can pass an `other` observable that will continue in case of timeout:

```cs
// Applies a timeout policy for each element in the observable sequence. If the
// next element isn't received within the specified timeout duration starting from
// its predecessor, the other observable sequence is used to produce future messages
// from that point on.
public static IObservable<TSource> Timeout<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
    TimeSpan dueTime, IObservable<TSource> other);
```

You could use this overload directly, or use it as a building block of a custom `Timeout` operator that accepts a `timeoutMessage` argument:

```cs
/// <summary>In case of timeout propagates a TimeoutException with custom message.</summary>
public static IObservable<TSource> Timeout<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, string timeoutMessage)
{
    return source.Timeout(dueTime,
        Observable.Throw<TSource>(new TimeoutException(timeoutMessage)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Will wait for a day before accepting it as answer.